# How is it physically possible for all four of the rivers in parshas breishis to come from Gan Eden?

Tags: parashat-bereishit

I read that Gihon is actually the Nile and I was wondering how that’s physically possible considering that the Nile flows from Lake Victoria which isn’t remotely close to the Tigris or the Euphrates.

Comment: where did you read that Gihon is the Nile?

Comment: I can’t remember exactly but it seems pretty obvious from pshat of the text. What other river flows through Ethiopia?

Comment: Why assume it's physically possible?

Comment: Because I believe the Torah is true

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/3082157/jewish/Where-Are-the-Four-Rivers-that-Come-from-Eden.htm You might find this interesting; it asks your exact question and has some great explanations.

Comment: How is it physically possible for a snake to talk?

Comment: See the Radak on the pasuk ושם הנהר השני גיחון

Comment: "What other river flows through Ethiopia?" The text doesn't mention Ethiopia. It mentions Kush. While that isn't such a leap, it is an interpretation. One that may be questioned particularly in light of how the names of the rivers are translated/interpreted.

Comment: where is gan eden?

Answer (score 3):

The Ben Ish Chai [writes](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1401&st=&pgnum=224) in the name of the Arizal that Gan Eden is not composed of physical matter similar to the rest of our world, but something much more refined. He also uses this to explain how the Gemara in Maseches Pesachim 94a could say Gan Eden is sixty times the size of the world: since it is of a very holy and refined matter, it does not take up physical space as we perceive it.

With this understanding of Gan Eden, the pesukim referring to a river leaving Gan Eden and turning into the four rivers we know of today cannot be referring to something we would be physically able to observe, just as we cannot observe actual Gan Eden.

(Interestingly, the Ben Ish Chai is very skeptical of scientific knowledge, and writes at length of its limitations. His understanding of Gan Eden would seem to be purely based on Torah sources.)